# print table javascript shows up as plain text

Tags: javascript, ajax

I am trying to print a table using javascript

the table html is like this:

```
    <table id="rounded" runat=server  summary="2007 Major IT Companies' Profit" style="position:relative;left:-45px;"  >

        <tr>
            <th scope="col" class="rounded-company">header1</th>
        <th scope="col" class="rounded-q1">header2</th>

            <th scope="col" class="rounded-q1">header3</th>
             <th scope="col" class="rounded-q1">header4</th>
              <th scope="col" class="rounded-q1">header5</th>
               <th scope="col" class="rounded-q1">header6</th>
                <th scope="col" class="rounded-q1">header7</th>
                 <th scope="col" class="rounded-q1">header8</th>

                   <th scope="col" class="rounded-q1">header9</th>
                   <th scope="col" class="rounded-q4"> header10</th>


        </tr>


</table>
```

I bring the table's data throw ajax so in the end the table look like this:

```
<table id="rounded" runat=server  summary="2007 Major IT Companies' Profit" style="position:relative;left:-45px;"  >

            <tr>
                <th scope="col" class="rounded-company">header1</th>
            <th scope="col" class="rounded-q1">header2</th>

                <th scope="col" class="rounded-q1">header3</th>
                 <th scope="col" class="rounded-q1">header4</th>
                  <th scope="col" class="rounded-q1">header5</th>
                   <th scope="col" class="rounded-q1">header6</th>
                    <th scope="col" class="rounded-q1">header7</th>
                     <th scope="col" class="rounded-q1">header8</th>

                       <th scope="col" class="rounded-q1">header9</th>
                       <th scope="col" class="rounded-q4"> header10</th>


            </tr>
<tr>
                <td>value1</td>
                <td>value2</td>

                <td>value3</td>
                <td>value4</td>
                <td></td>
                <td>value6</td>
                <td>value7</td>
                <td>value8</td>

                <td>value9</td>
                <td>value10</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>value1</td>
                <td>value2</td>

                <td>value3</td>
                <td>value4</td>
                <td></td>
                <td>value6</td>
                <td>value7</td>
                <td>value8</td>

                <td>value9</td>
                <td>value10</td>
            </tr>

</table>
```

I am using javascript to print the table like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function printTable()

{


    var disp_setting = "toolbar=yes,location=no,directories=yes,menubar=yes,";
    disp_setting += "scrollbars=yes,width=1350, height=800";
    var content_vlue = $("#rounded").html();


    var docprint = window.open("", "", disp_setting);
    docprint.document.open();
    docprint.document.write('<link href="css/table2.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />');  
    docprint.document.write('<html><head><title>Inel Power System</title>');
    docprint.document.write('</head><body onLoad="self.print()"><center>');
    docprint.document.write(content_vlue);
    docprint.document.write('</center></body></html>');
    docprint.document.close();
    docprint.focus(); 
}

</script>
```

the problem is that the table is printed as innertext instead of innerhtml(no rows no columns no header)

If I take this table (from page source ) and try to print it(without ajax) it works just fine.

What could be the problem?

Thanking you in advance for any help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to include the `<table>` tag in the HTML you're writing to the print document. Calling `.html()` just gets you what's *inside* the table tags.

Alternatively you could wrap the table in another element (a `<div>` or something) and then:

```
var content_vlue = $('#rounded').parent().html();
```

Comment: that was quick ! Pointy you are the best